# Google instant previews and adsense

Tags: google-adsense, google-search

I have a site with a normal image header, a menu,
then below that an adsense leaderboard, and then the content below that.

The problem is that google instant previews, capture the adsense text and hightlights it (puts it in a box) at google instant previews of my pages.
I really don't like the ad text be emphasized as the most important of my previews.
Maybe google preview bot is doing that because adsense text is on the top.

How I could either make instant preview ignore adsense text, or somehow reposition the adsense div with css, so that even if it's loaded after the content to be able to be positioned on the top of it?

I use 960 grid

Comment: Google Instant Previews show pages the same way any WebKit browser would [[source](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-instant-previews#08)]. It attempts to show pages the same way your site's visitors see them. If you want to change how predominant the ad block is for Google Preview, you'd have to change how predominant it is for all your visitors.

Comment: @Nick, that's what my research showed too, so make your comment an answer. "No, you can't do that" is a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

Google Instant Previews show pages the same way any WebKit browser would do, which is the same way your visitors see your site. From [Google's Site Preview FAQ](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-instant-previews#08):

> "The preview generator renders JavaScript, AJAX, CSS3, frames, and iframes in the same way that a Chrome / Webkit-based browser would."

If you want to change how predominant the AdSense ad is in Google's previews, you'd have to change how predominant it is for all your visitors.

Alternatively, you can [prevent Google Instant Previews on your site](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35304) altogether by using the `nosnippet` meta tag:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="nosnippet">
```

Note that this would also remove the text that appears below your page title that describes your page in Google's search results, which may be less than ideal.

Comment: By the looks of it, the reason your AdSense is highlighted is because it has matching text.

Comment: Yes it has matching text. I don't think it is wise to take out. My question above is also how i can reposition the adsense code, so that it is lower in the code, but higher in appearance, with css.

Comment: @john If you're looking to do that for performance reasons, you could use the [jQuery lazyload plugin](http://www.web2ajax.fr/2010/10/19/jquery-lazyload-ad-v1-4-new-version-of-defer-ad-plugin/) to defer loading of ads.

Comment: Thanks nick. I m looking to do it for seo reasons. so that potential visitors don't see emphasized the text of a random ad